# Keep values in html form below set amount

Tags: javascript, html, forms

In my form there is to be a choice of 3 bundles to choose from. Lets just call them Bundle 1, 2 and 3.

The form would look something like this...

**Select up to 3 bundles. Enter the number you require of max qty 3 in total:**
Bundle 1 [    ]
Bundle 2 [    ]
Bundle 3 [    ]

The markup is currently this:

```
<div id="formArea"><label for="first_name">Vorname<span class="formAsterisk">*</span>:<br />
        </label>   <input type="text" maxlength="40" size="40" id="first_name" class="textInput" name="first_name" /></div>
        <div id="formArea"><label for="last_name">Nachname<span class="formAsterisk">*</span>:<br />
        </label>   <input type="text" maxlength="80" size="40" id="last_name" class="textInput" name="last_name" /></div>
        <div id="formArea"><label for="company">Firma<span class="formAsterisk">*</span>:<br />
        </label>   <input type="text" maxlength="40" size="40" id="company" class="textInput" name="company" /></div>
        <div id="formArea">An welchem Bundle sind Sie interessiert? (Max Qty 3)<span class="formAsterisk"> *</span>:<br />
        <label for="bundle1">Bundle 1: <select name="bundle1">
        <option>0</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        </select></label> <label for="bundle2">Bundle 2: <select name="bundle2">
        <option>0</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        </select></label> <label for="bundle3">Bundle 3: <select name="bundle3">
        <option>0</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        </select></label>​</div>
        <div id="formArea"><label for="email">Email<span class="formAsterisk">*</span>:<br />
        </label>   <input type="text" maxlength="40" size="40" id="email" class="textInput" name="email" /></div>
        <div id="formArea"><label for="phone">Telefonnummer<span class="formAsterisk">*</span>:<br />
        </label>   <input type="text" maxlength="40" size="40" id="phone" class="textInput" name="phone" /></div>
        <div id="formArea">Adresse<span class="formAsterisk">*</span>:<br />
        <textarea type="text" id="00N50000001puIQ" class="textInput" wrap="soft" cols="40" name="00N50000001puIQ"></textarea></div>
        <div id="formArea">Stadt<span class="formAsterisk">*</span>:<br />
        <input type="text" maxlength="40" size="40" id="00N50000001puIC" class="textInput" name="00N50000001puIC" /></div>
        <div id="formArea">PLZ<span class="formAsterisk">*</span>:<br />
        <input type="text" maxlength="20" size="40" id="00N50000001puIZ" class="textInput" name="00N50000001puIZ" /></div>
        <div id="formArea">Land<span class="formAsterisk">*</span>:<br />
        <select title="Lead Country" id="00N50000001puID" class="textInput" name="00N50000001puID">
        <option value="">--Ausw&auml;hlen--</option>
        <option value="Austria">Austria</option>
        <option value="Belgium">Belgium</option>
        <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
        <option value="Ireland">Ireland</option>
        <option value="France">France</option>
        <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
        <option value="Spain">Spain</option>
        <option value="Portugal">Portugal</option>
        <option value="Switzerland">Switzerland</option>
        <option value="Italy">Italy</option>
        <option value="Netherlands">Netherlands</option>
        <option value="Luxembourg">Luxembourg</option>
        <option value="OTHER">OTHER</option>
        </select></div>
        <div id="formArea">Position<span class="formAsterisk">*</span>:<br />
        <select title="Job Role" id="00N50000001puIX" class="textInput" name="00N50000001puIX">
        <option value="Administrative assistant">Assistant/in</option>
        <option value="Customer Services Manager">Callcenter Manager/in</option>
        <option value="Director">Director</option>
        <option value="Facilities Manager">Einkaufsleiter</option>
        <option value="IT Manager">IT-Manager</option>
        <option value="Office Manager">Personalleiter/in</option>
        <option value="Office Worker">B&uuml;romitarbeiter</option>
        <option value="Receptionist">Sekret&auml;rin</option>
        <option value="Sales Manager / Representative">Vertriebsmitarbeiter</option>
        <option value="Team Leader / Manager">Teamleiter</option>
        <option value="Telecommunications Manager">Telekommunikationsmanager</option>
        <option value="Other">Sonstiges</option>
        </select></div>
        <div id="formArea">Unternehmensgr&ouml;&szlig;e<span class="formAsterisk">*</span>:<br />
        <select title="Number of Employees" id="00N50000001puIH" class="textInput" name="00N50000001puIH">
        <option value="">--Ausw&auml;hlen--</option>
        <option value="10 or less">10 oder weniger</option>
        <option value="11-49">11-49</option>
        <option value="50-99">50-99</option>
        <option value="100-249">100-249</option>
        <option value="250-499">250-499</option>
        <option value="500 or more">500 oder mehr</option>
        </select></div>
        <div id="formArea"><label for="first_name">                 <input type="checkbox" name="marketing" id="marketing" />                 Opt-in for regular marketing<span class="formAsterisk">*</span><br />
        </label></div>
        <div id="formArea"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Jetzt Testen" /></div>
```

So for example, you could only enter Bundle 1: 0, Bundle 2: 1 and Bundle 3: 2.

Not sure if this is the best way of doing it using text entry boxes, but open to suggestions.

How can I achieve this using Javascript?

Thanks

Comment: are you fighting with the algorithm or with javascript basics?

Comment: can you show your form markup?

Comment: The javascript. Tried looking for a solution by searching the site but could find any answers.

Comment: Could you please make a fiddle with what you have tried so far?

Comment: @PedrodelSol added the markup I currently have.

Comment: Could you go into more detail about exactly what it is you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Is jQuery an option or do you need it in plain JavaScript?

Comment: Added a jQuery solution if you're interested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/k2647/)**?

**jQuery**

```
var x = 3;
$('select').change(function() {
    var sum = 3;
    $('select').each(function() {
        sum = sum - $(this).val();
    });
    $('select').not($(this)).each(function() {
        //            console.log($(this).val());
        $('option', this).each(function() {
            $(this).prop('disabled',($(this).val() > sum)?true:false);
        });
    });
});​
```

**HTML**

```
<label for="bundle1">Bundle 1:
<select name="bundle1">
    <option>0</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    </select></label>
<label for="bundle2">Bundle 2:
<select name="bundle2">
    <option>0</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    </select></label>
<label for="bundle3">Bundle 3:
<select name="bundle3">
    <option>0</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    </select></label>​
```

Comment: I went for your solution in the end, many thanks but... if I add other drop down menu options to the form it no longer works. How can we get around this? Thanks

Comment: I'd need to see what changes you made to determine that.

Comment: Hi, I just added the full markup of the form to the original question. I believe the cause of it not working when actually in the form to be because of the other dropdowns. Maybe your code can be tweaked to specify bundle1, bundle2 and bundle3?

Comment: I'm looking at it now. The first thing I can tell you is that your IDs need to be unique. Right now you're duplicating some (e.g. `formArea`).

Comment: And that was your problem. If you use unique IDs then you can reference the specific group of selects. So instead of using `$('#select')`, use `$('#formAreaX select')`, where `#formareaX` is the unique ID parent div.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it further. I tried your suggestions but it's still not working. Might be useful if you look at the live site instead? http://esp.plantronics.com/conference_de_citrix

Comment: Here's an updated fiddle with the revised HTML you posted above: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/k2647/12/. Notice that I changed the ID for the div that contains the select boxes. You should change all your IDs to be unique.

Answer (score 1):

something like this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function countBundles(){

    var bundle1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('bundle1').value, 10);
    var bundle2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('bundle2').value, 10);
    var bundle3 = parseInt(document.getElementById('bundle3').value, 10);

    if (bundle1+bundle2+bundle3>3){
        alert("too many bundles");
    }

}
</script>
```

```
<form name="bundles">
<label for="bundle1">Bundle 1:<br /></label>
<input type="text" maxlength="1" size="10" id="bundle1" class="textInput" name="bundle1" onchange="countBundles()"/>
<label for="bundle2">Bundle 2:<br /></label>
<input type="text" maxlength="1" size="10" id="bundle2" class="textInput" name="bundle2" onchange="countBundles()"/>
<label for="bundle3">Bundle 3:<br /></label>
<input type="text" maxlength="1" size="10" id="bundle3" class="textInput" name="bundle3" onchange="countBundles()"/>
</form>
```